# How can I launch a Office product from Azure web application

Tags: c#, azure, ms-office

I've built a web application hosted in Azure and I need it to launch a Office application on the end users desktop when running a specific part of the process.  The application I need to launch is MS Project Professional and I can do that without issue if I am running the site locally but I really need to make this work while the application is published and running in the cloud.  I can post a code example if needed but I believe I need to add something to request the end user to allow access (just a guess).  Note that the end user will always be an admin on the box they are working on.  If anyone has any suggested approaches I would appreciate the insight.  Again my application works fully if I am running it locally but I don't want to install it on a clients system I want to run it from the cloud.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll find Office URL schemas are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes)

To launch Microsoft Project, set the href/link to `ms-project:ofv|u|https://path-to-resource` for read only
or `ms-project:ofe|u|https://path-to-resource` for write access

I don't have Project, so I can't test these, but they do load for Word and Excel

Comment: Thanks a ton on this!!  If you happen to have a C# example for Word or Excel that would be great.  At the moment I am using a Process.Start(@"winproj.exe", " s/ " + "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa").  I would convert to Process.Start(ms-project:ofv|u| + URL)   I will give it a shot and respond with results.  I will also post the code for other as an example...

Comment: @Don as it is a URL, putting it inside `Process.Start("ms-project:ofv|u|https://path-to-file");` should work. If you are running it as a web app, you probably want to launch it by a link or get the web app to return the url as a redirect.

Comment: unfortunately MS Project Professional seems to be not an office product but a stand alone application even though its in the Office 16 directory.  I've tried a few variations with no success.  The result I get if I use the following var objProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\winproj.exe", "/s " + OnlinePWA); is a 502 error.  This code runs fine when I run locally.   Unless MS Project Professional is referenced differently than ms-project.

Comment: @Don if you are running `Process.Start()` on a web server, it will try to launch the contents the server, not the client. If you are trying to launch it on the client, you should use a link for the user to click with the schema inside or if possible return a 302 redirect to prompt the browser to open the user's copy of the app.

Comment: All thanks for all your help but fortunately microsoft updated it's csom object model for project online to allow setting of lag tasks duration so I no longer need to use the end client application.